# Which is the Fastest Data Collection?

Tags: c#, ado.net

In a web application, I have to select ~1 million rows from a SQL view.
These million rows are then used to display a bar chart with drill down functionality.

I am bringing all of the data in one go and letting the user drill down on the data collection that is held in the memory.

I am using ADO.Net (SqlCommand) to get data from the database.

How do I store the data in the data collection that provides fastest data access? Is DataTable better or SqlReader or Arrays or List?  Please suggest

Comment: Sounds like a perfect candidate for your own benchmarking.

Comment: Meaning, devise a test and run it on the different types of collections you're considering to get some metrics. The speed is going depend on how you're accessing the data and other algorithm-specific details.

Comment: If you must access the 1 million rows from memory then the fastest data structure to use will depend on the access patterns in your code - i.e. how do you need to access the data?  Without this information it's difficult to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to let the user drill down through ~1M records?

Typically, you'd retrieve an unfiltered dataset if the user needs to see all of it at once, and drill down in the UI. However, with so many records, there's no way that they'd be able to take in the whole set unless, perhaps, you're displaying them graphically, like GIS or other graphical data points.

You may be better off asking yourself if you can initially show them a summary/aggregate view (which you could obtain through a stored procedure), and let them drill down through that by requerying the database with whatever filter parameters they select.

The SQL server is *very* good at handling this type of operation. Let your investment work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I am going with this solution. The only problem is that I am opening and closing database connection and then calling a stored procedure eachtime.  It is slowing the application as it's a quite expensive task.  Any suggestions?